# Visualisation of isotopy

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

How can I visualise the meaning of isotopy that appears while defining *Teichmuller* space?
Can you suggest a picture where two maps are not isotopic? I want more clarification about isotopyic maps. Isotopy is sometimes referred to as homotopy via homeomorphism. I need geometric visualisation.

Comment: To put emphasis on words here, you can use Markdown , in particular `_underscores_` for italics. Please don't use LaTeX math mode to italicise words, especially when writing a document in LaTeX!

Comment: For starters, do you know the definition of isotopy? Do you know any examples?